# Escrever no campo de pesquisa data no formato dd/mm/YYYY e pesquisar no banco no formato YYYY-mm-dd

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Quero digitar no formulário a data no formato dd/mm/YYYY porem pesquisar no banco no formato YYYY-mm-dd, Por favor já tentei de tudo, da um HELP Ai

Comment: Utilize a classe `DateTime`, tem a função estática `createFromFormat` e a função `format` para extrair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em **MySQL** existe a função `STR_TO_DATE`, que recebe como parâmetro a sua `string` de data e converte para uma data válida na consulta **SQL**:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE("01/12/2018", '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Retorna: `2018-12-01`

Answer (score 2):

```
$data = substr($obj->getData(), 8, 2);
$data .= "/";
$data .= substr($obj->getData(), 5, 2);
$data .= "/";
$data .= substr($obj->getData(), 0, 4);
```

Comment: você pode usar "substring" onde no exemplo acima "obj->getData()" é a sua data que vem do Banco!